# Como selecionar códigos com diferentes tamanhos em pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Em Python 3, com pandas, tenho esse dataframe com vários códigos nas colunas "CPF_CNPJ_doador" e "CPF_CNPJ_doador_originario"

```
cand_doacoes = pd.read_csv("doacoes_csv.csv",sep=';',encoding = 'latin_1',  decimal = ",")

cand_doacoes.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 427489 entries, 0 to 427488
Data columns (total 12 columns):
UF                                427489 non-null object
Partido                           427489 non-null object
Cargo                             427489 non-null object
Nome_candidato                    427489 non-null object
CPF_candidato                     427489 non-null int64
CPF_CNPJ_doador                   426681 non-null float64
Nome_doador                       427489 non-null object
Nome_doador_Receita               427489 non-null object
Valor                             427489 non-null float64
CPF_CNPJ_doador_originario        427489 non-null object
Nome_doador_originario            427489 non-null object
Nome_doador_originario_Receita    427489 non-null object
dtypes: float64(2), int64(1), object(9)
memory usage: 39.1+ MB
```

Os códigos nas colunas "CPF_CNPJ_doador" e "CPF_CNPJ_doador_originario" são sempre números inteiros e com diferentes tamanhos: 14 dígitos, 13 dígitos, 11 dígitos ou 10 dígitos

Eu preciso criar um dataframe apenas com códigos de 14 e 13 dígitos. Por favor, alguém sabe como posso selecionar no dataframe "cand_doacoes" apenas os códigos de 14 e 13 dígitos na coluna "CPF_CNPJ_doador"? É preciso antes transformar em string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

de acordo com as informações do dataframe acima, os CPFs que você está tratando são float64, o que facilita um pouco as coisas.

Você pode fazer um `slice` no seu dataframe pegando só os valores que te interessa. Para isso, você pode aplicar uma função que detecta o tamanho dos CPFs da coluna desejada.

Aqui eu utilizo a função `apply` com uma função anônima `lambda` como parâmetro que faz os cálculos pra mim.

```py
df[df['CPF_CNPJ_doador'].apply(lambda x: len(str(x)) == 13 or len(str(x)) == 14)]
```